# How to export my DataGridView to a csv file?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to export my `DataGridView` to `csv` file with this code:

```
private void saveToCsv(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
{
    if (dGV.RowCount > 0)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = dGV.DataSource as DataTable;
        int d = dt.Columns.Count;
        int c = dt.Rows.Count;
        foreach (var column in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray())
        {
            if (dt.AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr.IsNull(column)))
                d--;
        }
        string stOutput = "";
        DataGridViewRow ds = new DataGridViewRow();
        StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(filename);

        //write header rows to csv
        for (int i = 0; i <= d - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                swOut.Write(",");
            }
            swOut.Write(dGV.Columns[i].HeaderText);
        }

        swOut.WriteLine();

        //write DataGridView rows to csv
        for (int j = 0; j <= c - 1; j++)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[j].IsNull)
            if (j > 0)
            {
                swOut.WriteLine();
            }

            ds = dGV.Rows[j];

            for (int i = 0; i <= d - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    swOut.Write(",");
                }

                stOutput = ds.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                //replace comma's with spaces
                stOutput = stOutput.Replace(',', ' ');
                //replace embedded newlines with spaces
                stOutput = stOutput.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");

                swOut.Write(stOutput);
            }
        }
        swOut.Close();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Data successfully saved");
}
```

but the output is this:

```
0.512,45,tested_negative
0.966,33,tested_negative
0.42,35,tested_negative
0.665,46,tested_positive
0.329,29,tested_negative
,,
,,
,,
,,
,,
,,
,,
,,
```

The empty rows get exported too.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: why writing commas and the data separately you just iterate over and       var `data= string.Format("{0},{1}", first, second);`

Comment: `if (dt.Rows[j].IsNull) continue;`

Answer (score 0):

1st you should qualify your text data incase they have commas in them if your going to create a comma delimited file

taken from stackoverflow  (ref [Exporting datagridview to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943787/exporting-datagridview-to-csv-file))

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

var headers = dGV.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>();
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", headers.Select(column => "\"" + column.HeaderText + "\"").ToArray()));

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var cells = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>();

    string temp string.Join(",", cells.Select(cell => "\"" + cell.Value + "\"").ToArray())
    temp = temp.Replace(",","");
    temp = temp.Replace("\"","");
    if(temp.Length > 0)
    {
      sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", cells.Select(cell => "\"" + cell.Value + "\"").ToArray()));
    }
}
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\test\hereIam.csv");
file.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); //
```

Comment: he is replacing any `,`  in his data. did you scan his code?  You should add a quote to your source if you copy and paste this code from some other content.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stick with your code, check the  `stOutput` - if it is `',,'` do not write it into the file.

You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/a/4959869/7505395 - one of the answers to [c# datatable to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959722/c-sharp-datatable-to-csv)

```
// ... your code ...

if ( stOutput != ",,")
    swOut.Write(stOutput); 
else suppressNewLine = true;  // suppress newline above, and reset bool to false

// ... more of your code ...
```

You have to fix the empty newlines after that.

Best thing to do would be to assemble each line (or the whole table *gasp*) into a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) - and write it only once (or at least line-wise) to the file when (line or whole table) is fully assembled.

StringBuilders are *build* for itereatively adding to them and should make your code much faster.

Comment: Better to not write the empty row in the first place than to check for `',,'`

Comment: @mason - thats why I qualified it with _"if you want to stick with your code"_ and provided a better solution from another question. He is performing data-replacement on his data so the line might be empty after all those replacements, not before, thats why skipping it before his data-replace-maniputlations is more difficult - and the check prevents the now-empty line to be written.