# How to customize format when export datagrid to txt file?

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to export my datagrid to txt file with format like this:

```
//inside txt file, each item on one row
item1[id],item1[name]
item2[id],item2[name]
```

Something like that, with each item on one row, split by a comma.
Currently my code is like this:

```
        var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        var file = Path.Combine(directory, "123.txt");
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < datagrid.Items.Count; i++)
        {
         ////////My Setting class
            Setting setting= (Setting)datagrid.Items[i];
         //////// I need help for the below lines with formatting
            strBuilder.Append(setting.id);
            strBuilder.Append(setting.name);


        }
        File.WriteAllText(file, strBuilder.ToString());
```

Also my second question is : the output directory of 123.txt file is in bin/debug folder, can i change it to the current working directory/work space of the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this link for details sample [export-data-from-a-datagrid](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/09/29/export-data-from-a-datagrid/) or this [exporting-datagrid-to-csv-without-a-gui-in-wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348206/exporting-datagrid-to-csv-without-a-gui-in-wpf)

or if you want to just export use this code :

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    dataGrid1.SelectAllCells();
    dataGrid1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
    ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dataGrid1);
    dataGrid1.UnselectAllCells();
    String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
    File.AppendAllText("D:\\test.csv", result, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8);

}
```

for path issue use "..\" [how-to-navigate-a-few-folders-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899422/how-to-navigate-a-few-folders-up)