# Remove last (empty) entry from StringBuilder object, when exporting to CSV

Tags: c#, datagridview, export-to-csv, stringbuilder

I want to remove the last (empty) row of a StringBuilder Object

EDIT: The empty row is from the "AllowUserToAddRows" how can i skip it?

- c# Forms application
- dataGridView1 on form2
- I want Export to CSV (separated by semicolon)  [btw. it's just one column]
- It Could happen, that a previously created CSV is parsed to the dataGridView again

I use a altered solution from here:
[Exporting datagridview to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943787/exporting-datagridview-to-csv-file/26259909#26259909)

my code

```
void SaveDataGridViewToCSV(string filename)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var headers = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>();
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", headers.Select(column => "" + column.HeaderText + ";").ToArray()));

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        var cells = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>();
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", cells.Select(cell => "" + cell.Value + ";").ToArray()));
    }

    try
    {
        File.WriteAllText(filename, sb.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception exceptionObject)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exceptionObject.ToString());
    }
}
```

**The sb.ToString looks like this**  `{Coumn;90;90;626;626;;}`

**The "real" StringBuilder Object as String is:** `{Coumn;\r\n90;\r\n90;\r\n626;\r\n626;\r\n;}`

I want to remove the empty last row.

I tried to parse the stringbuilder to a string, and then remove last semicolon
but with no success (i have problem with the End Of Line.)

```
string s = sb.ToString();
while (s.EndsWith(";\r\n;") == true)
{
    s.Substring(0, s.Length - 5);
}
```

I tried to remove last element of array, but StingBuilder is no array

I'm stuck.

Comment: If you only have 1 column, why bothering with `string.Join` for the cells?

Comment: @dymanoid looks like a copy and paste of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16295690/6144259)

Comment: Note that `Substring` does not _modify_ the string - try `s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 5);`

Comment: @dymanoid yes that's a point; could be more columns in the future @A Friend as stated in the question, Yes its derived from that answer

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just not add the empty line in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

As i found out the empty set is always exported to the csv.
It's from the ability that the user can input data to the dataGridView, and there is always a empty, active row.

if i disable dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows the empty row for userinput is not within the stringbuilder set of data.

```
   void SaveDataGridViewToCSV(string filename)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        //SOLUTION disable AllowUserInput to avoid empty set saved to CSV
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        var headers = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>();
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", headers.Select(column => "" + column.HeaderText + ";").ToArray()));

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            var cells = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>();
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", cells.Select(cell => "" + cell.Value + ";").ToArray()));
        }

        try
        {
            File.WriteAllText(filename, sb.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception exceptionObject)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exceptionObject.ToString());
        }
    }
```

thanks for help!