# Include whitespaces on exporting gridview to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I'm trying to export Gridview to Excel file.

Example SQL Database Record

`91091234   SAM      PLE      TEXT`
`89237416   SAMPLE     TEXT`

I've been able to bind it to Gridview including the multiple spaces. I've used this code to include those multiple spaces

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
   {
      cell.Text = cell.Text.Replace(" ", "&nbsp"); // need to modify this part, i think
   }
}
```

My code for exporting Gridview to Excel

```
private void _exportGV()
{
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Charset = "";
string FileName = "Instances" + ".xls";
StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
gv.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
gv.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
gv.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
Response.End();
}
```

So my problem is when I export the data shows like this

`91091234   SAM&nbspPLE&nbspTEXT`
`89237416   SAMPLE&nbspTEXT`

How do I retain the multiple spaces without replacing it to &nbsp?

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293207/5836671) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39513057/5836671). All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: **1.** Do not replace those spaces **2.** Use StringBuilder to write the data from the grid to a .Csv file. It's like writing to a text file. This file can be directly opened in Excel.

Comment: OR you can use [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943787/exporting-datagridview-to-csv-file) method as well

Comment: The &nbsp is not a character that Excel can understand. Try exporting data cell by cell, leaving spaces unconverted. Using Interop classes may be more effective rather than using HtmlTextWriter.